# Write out object properties path that is not exist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a code as below which is a simple object. The problem is if there is any user that imports my object and accesses properties that don't exist I need to write out the full path of the object properties.

I think about the Proxy class but still do not have a clue .

```
var myLocalize = {
    home : "content of abc"
};


var useMyLoc = new Proxy(myLocalize, {
    get(target, prop, receiver){
        if(!target[prop])
        {
            Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
                get: () => {
                    return new Proxy({
                        toString() {
                            return target.toString() + "." + prop;
                        }
                    }, useMyLoc);
                }
            });
        }
        return target[prop];
    }
});


console.log(useMyLoc.home.title.desc.plain); 

// expect the output of the code should be:  'myLocalize.home.title.desc.plain'
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a JavaScript object, not a [JSON object](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad explain , i will update it

Comment: `console.log` will generally not call `toString`. It is up to the console implementation how they render objects. So what you want is not possible unless the driver code does something to coerce the object to string.

Comment: *"if there is any user that imports my object and accesses properties that don't exist I need to write out the full path"*: so it is not the user that performs the `console.log`? But in that case you need to place `console.log` inside your "non-user" code.

Comment: It is not possible to detect the end of a property access chain from within the property access. The chain needs to be explicitly terminated, e.g. by `useMyLoc.home.title.desc.plain.toString()`.